# import cannot be resolved(Spring with java classes)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to use java classes in web application based on Spring MVC framework

i try to use `<%@ page import="class_j" %>`,i tried also accessing using the package name.ClasseName `class_j.GetAllFonction`and i googled too but in vain

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: please put your code and not a picture

Comment: the principle is to understand the issue ,and if you tried to answer me instead of this comment may be better ,anyway thank you

Comment: mmmm, ok ......

Comment: thank you for your understanding

Answer (score 0):

Add language of the page for example

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
```